# Convergence on sum of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, computability, absolute-convergence

Let $\{ a_n \}^\infty_1 \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ be a sequence. If for any recursively enumerable set $S = \{k_1, k_2, ...\} \subseteq \Bbb{N}$, where $k_1 < k_2 < ...$ is an infinite ascending chain, $\sum^\infty_{i=1} a_{k_i}$ converges, can we conclude that $\sum^\infty_{i=1} a_{i}$ converges **absolutely**? Although we usually construct a conditionally convergent series using a particular pattern, I think there must be a counterexample with the help of a non-computable number. However I am not familiar with computability, so I ask for help.

Comment: What value do the words, " recursively enumerable" add to the question? I am not that familiar with them, but upon first glance with it's definition, it doesn't make a difference, so aren't these words redundant?

Comment: @AdamRubinson The number of subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ is uncountable, so there must be non-computable subset that $S$ can not reach.

Comment: @AdamRubinson By the way, if you can prove that even with all subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ the sum converging, we can still not conclude that $\sum a_i$ converges absolutely, then yes, "recursively enumerable" is reduntant.

Comment: A real series is either absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent (and cannot be both). If it is conditionally convergent, then there must be ascending chains such that the subseries corresponding to those chains diverge to $\ +\infty,\ $ and other subseries with other ascending chains diverge to $\ -\infty.\ $ This is not the Riemann Series Theorem, but rather a property of conditionally convergent series (hint: look at the definition of CC series). So if all subseries (whilst not rearranging order of terms) converge, then the original series must converge absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll construct a counterexample.

A maximal r.e. set is a set $M\subseteq\omega$ such that:

(1) $M$ is r.e.;
(2) $\omega\setminus M$ is infinite;
and (3) for every r.e. set $X\supseteq M,$ either $X\setminus M$ is finite or $X$ is cofinite.

($X$ is cofinite means that $\omega\setminus X$ is finite.)

Friedberg proved that maximal r.e. sets exist.

$$ $$

Let $M$ be a maximal r.e. set.  List $\omega\setminus M$ in increasing order: $u_1 \lt u_2 \lt u_3 \lt\dots.$  (This is not a recursive enumeration.)

Define $a_n$ for $n\lt\omega$ by setting:

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{(-1)^j}{j}, & \text{if }n=u_j;\cr
0, & \text{if }n\in M.
\end{cases}$$

Note that the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, but that series is **not absolutely convergent.**

Now let $S$ be any infinite r.e. set; list S in increasing order: $k_1\lt k_2 \lt k_3\dots.$  (This is not necessarily a recursive enumeration.)  We'll show that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{k_j}$ converges.

Since $M\cup S$ is an r.e. set containing $M,$ we must have that either $S\setminus M = (M\cup S)\setminus M$ is finite or that $M\cup S$ is cofinite.  We handle each case separately:

$\bullet\;\;$ If $S\setminus M$ is finite, then the terms of $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{k_j}$ consist of infinitely many terms that are zero and only finitely many terms of the form $\frac{(-1)^j}j.$ So, in this case, the series converges.

$\bullet\;\;$ If $M\cup S$ is cofinite, then $S$ contains all but finitely many members of $\omega\setminus M$ (plus some members of $M$ as well).  So $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{k_j}$ consists of all but finitely many terms of $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}j$ (in the same order as in that series) interspersed with some zero terms, which again converges, completing the proof.

Comment: It's surprising to me that a maximal r.e. set exists, thanks!

Comment: It was surprising to me when I first saw it also.  You can read about the existence of maximal sets in *The Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability*, by Hartley Rogers, Jr.  As I recall, Rogers presents a proof by Yates that is simpler than Friedberg's original proof.